# Ionic 3 InAppBrowser interfering with Reactive form value updates

Tags: ionic3, angular2-forms, inappbrowser

I have implemented an Ionic 3 page with a Reactive form.

Some read-only, calculated fields on the form are updated dynamically based on changes to other fields. e.g.

```
this.myFormGroup.controls.myField.valueChanges.subscribe(
  (newMyFieldValue) => this.calculateValueForOtherField(newMyFieldValue)
);
```

This all works fine with calculated fields updated as the user types.

We then introduced an InAppBrowser page in a separate part of the app and once this browser page had been run (and closed), the dynamic form display no longer updates as the user types?

```
...
this.browser = this.iab.create(url, '_blank','location=no,zoom=no,clearsessioncache=yes');
...
this.browser.close();
```

We can force the display to update after making the calculation using ChangeDetectorRef, but this is not ideal:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
...
constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef);
...
this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
```

In Chrome inspector, we can see the "closed" InAppBrowser window remains, but not visible to the user as some sort of hidden tab?

Anyway, why is the InAppBrowser interfering with the display update and how to prevent it from doing so?